# NASM: how can i implement a stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm

I want to make a calculator in assembly that takes an arithmetic expression and output the result.

Something like:

```
((3 +7) * 21) - (45 -99)
```

Then i think i need two stacks: one for pushing the number and another for pushing the left parenthesis.

However i search around and have no result. People who answer similar question thought its a bad idea cause there's build-in stack.

SO my question is: is using another stack a bad idea ? If yes, what would be a good way to implement this . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can have finite stack you can change `rbp` and `rsp` and reserve some space in stack then you can use it like array or you some globally allocated array instead of reserving space in stack

if you must have infinite stack you must use linked list and in linux you must use something like `br()` system call in order to reserve space in heap or you can use C library function `malloc()` to do this for you.

This is a simple implementation of finite stack in GAS syntax (Generated from C source code by GCC)

```
    .local  S
    .comm   S,4096,32
    .local  head
    .comm   head,4,4
    .text
    .globl  push
push:
.LFB0:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    head(%rip), %eax
    cmpl    $1023, %eax
    jg      .L1
    movl    head(%rip), %eax
    cltq
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, S(,%rax,4)
    movl    head(%rip), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, head(%rip)
.L1:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.LFE0:
    .globl  pop
pop:
.LFB1:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    head(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle     .L4
    movl    head(%rip), %eax
    subl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, head(%rip)
    movl    head(%rip), %eax
    cltq
    movl    S(,%rax,4), %eax
    jmp     .L3
.L4:
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

In above code `S` is our stack array defined globally and `head` is a our stack head and again defined globally.